# operation time of method

Tags: c#

how to know, how much time take method in C#
for example, i have label1 and method

```
    public int MakeSome(int a, int b)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < b; j++)
            {
               // some operation
            }
        }
        return returnIntValue;
    }
```

know, how to know how many milliseconds take MakeSome method, and write value in label1.
thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the Stopwatch class from the System.Diagnostics namespace.

Comment: I have use this method, but I have difference values from 150 msek to 500 msek. is it normal? in same processor. Processor not overloaded.

Comment: I don't know. What are you doing in the loop?  Also, don't forget that you might be measuring the time spent in the jitter; the first time you run code can take orders of magnitude longer than the second if it is loading assemblies, running static initializers, and so on.

Answer (score 17):

You can use the [`Stopwatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class:

```
Stopwatch st = new Stopwatch();
st.Start();
// call MakeSome method...
st.Stop();
```

Then you can check the `st.ElapsedMilliseconds` property.

Answer (score 0):

Create a time variable and assign the DateTime.Now to it then subtract the two times.

(Use the Stopwatch class instead - it is more elegant)

Comment: You should realy rather use the Stopwatch class. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx

Comment: I just learned about that class - after all these years! Cool!